# TeamViewer is not working after automatic installation of kernel in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, kernel, teamviewer

I am using Teamviewer 14 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit OS. Just now, the OS popped up with some updates and it has updated the kernel i.e., `linux-image` which I was using without any issues. Please note that Teamviewer 14 was working on this kernel with no issues. However, after the update, Teamviewer 14 stopped working. Below are the logs-

```
ravi@home:~/.local/share/teamviewer14/logfiles$ ll
total 16
drwx------ 2 ravi ravi 4096 Dec 29 01:28 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 ravi ravi 4096 Oct 24 21:14 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravi ravi  153 Dec 29 01:28 gui.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravi ravi  200 Dec 29 01:28 startup.log
ravi@home:~/.local/share/teamviewer14/logfiles$ cat gui.log 
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5X11Extras.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ravi@home:~/.local/share/teamviewer14/logfiles$ cat startup.log 
Init...
TeamViewer:        14.1.3399 - DEB
Profile:           /home/ravi (ravi)
Desktop:           DS: 'ubuntu'     XDG: 'Unity'
XServer TTY:       7

ok (info)

CheckCPU: SSE2 support: yes
ok (profile)
```

I tried installing `Linux home 3.13.0-164-generic` but Teamviewer 14 still did not work. Below are the details of the current kernel-

```
ravi@home:~$ uname -a
Linux home 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am wondering how do make TeamViewer 14 working?

Comment: Have you checked the [Teamviewer Community site](https://community.teamviewer.com/?category.id=en) ?  Additionally, [this](https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/using-teamviewer-tar-package-on-ubuntu) link describes how to detect missing teamviewer required Ubuntu libraries and how to install them (although it doesn't mention which version of either Ubuntu or teamviewer).

Comment: Thanks, @TonyB. Downgrading to a minor version worked for me `sudo apt-get install teamviewer=14.0.14470`

Answer (score 0):

For me I use **Sysnaptic Package Manager** and install
 **libdouble-conversion1** and **libdouble-conversion-dev** then it working fine